# Iterate to get the substring

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to iterate through a pyspark dataframe and get the values after certain position. The data will be some thing like:

[image]

I need the value between the `.` and the   (space) in every row. Example for `SNO=1`, I need `1`.

I tried writing the below code and it says column not iterable

```
df3 = df2.withColumn("value", substring(df2.ColumnValue,instr(df2.ColumnValue,
'.') + 1, instr(df2.ColumnValue, ' ') - instr(df2.ColumnValue, '.') - 1))
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: `substring` function takes int values for `position`and `length` parameters but you're passing a column. If you want to pass column use it with SQL expression: `expr("substring(ColumnValue, instr(ColumnValue, '.') + 1, instr(ColumnValue, ' ') - instr(ColumnValue, '.') - 1)")`. Or simpler by splitting as mentioned in the above answer.

Comment: It did not work for some reason :(

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP_EXTRACT should do the trick:

`regexp_EXTRACT(<column>,<regex>,<group>)`

For your regex, try `(?<=\.)(.*?)(?=\ )`.  This is using look aheads and look behinds.  Here's a [great reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that explains it way better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Andrew said, [`regexp_extract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) is the best choice in this case. And my regex is a bit different `[^\.]+\.([^\s]+)`. You can play with it here https://regex101.com/r/cBtiT7/1

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('a', F.regexp_extract('col', '[^\.]+\.([^\s]+)', 1)).show()

+--------------------+---+
|                 col|  a|
+--------------------+---+
|    H1.1 Hello World|  1|
|H02.11 Hello World 2| 11|
+--------------------+---+
```